# Simulink: choosing an Arduino Digital Output based on a workspace variable

Tags: matlab, arduino, simulink

I have a Simulink model, the controller part of which I'm trying to code onto an embedded controller. Following the [example here](http://au.mathworks.com/help/supportpkg/arduino/examples/getting-started-with-arduino-hardware.html) I can toggle any specific pin, but appropriately setting the `Pin number` parameter of the `Arduino Digital Output` block.

However, I would like to set this parameter to a variable name which is available in the workspace (for example `myPinNumber`), doing so in the example works as expected, i.e. if I set `myPinNumber = 13` in the workspace, and set the `Pin number` parameter of the block to `myPinNumber` it behaves the same as if I'd directly written `13` in the block, all good.

However, it does not work when I try to set the `Pin Number` parameter to an element of an array. For example if I define `myPinNumbers = [12 13 14]`, and try to set the `Pin Number` parameter of the `Digital Output` block to `pinNumber(2)` I get the following error:

```
Error in 'model_folder/model_name/Digital Output1': Initialization commands cannot be evaluated.
Caused by:
Digital Output block parameter Pin number must be an integer between 0 and 53.
Component: Simulink | Category: Block error
```

Most other blocks in Simulink would allow setting a parameter value to a particular element of a work-space array in this way. Does anyone know of a fix/work-around?